# Laravel8 Property [Eng2] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am facing a strange problem: I have 2 pages with similar structure relating to same DB, the first one displaying a grid of products working perfectly, the second the item detail giving me this error. I can get the all `JSON string {{$wine}}` on the page but no way to extract elements with `{{$wine->Eng2}}` or `{{$wine['Eng2']}}`

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
```

```
@include('partials.sidebar')

<div class="detail-container">
    <img src="/img/9122705276958.png" alt="" />
    <ul>
        <!--<li>{{$wine}}</li>-->
        <li>{{$wine->Eng2}}</li>
      
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <!--<div class="addCart">
            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        </div>

        <ul class="side-icons">
            <span><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
            <span><i class="far fa-heart"></i></span>
            <span><i class="fas fa-sliders-h"></i></span>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="price">
            <li>Retail price: Ntd  </li>
            <li>Member price: Ntd  </li>
            <li>VIP price down to: Ntd  </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  -->
</div>
```

```
  public function detail($id) {
    $wine =Wine::where('ART','=',$id)->get(); 
   
    return view('detail', [
        'wine' => $wine
    ]);
        
}


Route::get('wines', [WineController::class,'index']);    

Route::get('/wines/{id}',[WineController::class,'query']);

Route::get('detail/{id}', [WineController::class,'detail']);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly. So much to learn ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$wine = Wine::where('ART','=',$id)->first();
```

instead of

```
$wine = Wine::where('ART','=',$id)->get();
```

`first()` will get you the first element in the collection but `get()` will get you the whole collection, so you can use `first()` if the collection has one element, or you have to use foreach in the view.